# Tool to grab items from a Listbox in external app

Tags: windows, user-interface

I need to grab text items from a listbox in an application. I know for sure that the control is a ListBox. I've seen many tools that could do this, but I cannot remember their names. And I cannot find the right words to google for it. Does anybody know such tool?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't find anything and ended up writing a small C# application using System.Windows.Automation. Just several lines of code.

Answer (score 0):

You just get hold of the window handle of the list box and send some LB_GETTEXT messages. As far as tools go you might be thinking of Spy.

Comment: Not Spy++ itself, but a similar tool. I have already solved it with a small console app and Microsoft UI Automation Framework. But I do remember using tools that allowed to point to a list and get all the text lines from it.